# gatsby-source-shopify shows timedout error on build

Tags: shopify, gatsby

I encounter an `ETIMEDOUT error` whenever I try to use the [gatsby-source-shopify](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-shopify) to build a gatsby site connected to my Shopify store.
With a small store, this works perfectly but with a large store like the clients I'm working with that has over 1000 products, it shows a timed out error, both during development and when deployed to Netlify.

My issue is similar to that at this [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14300) but I have tried all the suggested and still face the same issue.